# Unable to inject @ApplicationScoped bean in JAX-RS service

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi

I've created JAX-RS service in which I want to inject an application scoped bean. The problem is that the bean is not injected. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

JAX-RS service:

```
@Path("room")
public class RoomService {

    @Inject
    GameController gc;

    public RoomService() {}

    @Path("create")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String create() {
        Room r = new Room();
        gc.addRoom(r); // gc is null
        return r.toJson();
    }
}
```

Application scoped bean

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import pepuch.multuplayergameserver.entity.Game;
import pepuch.multuplayergameserver.entity.Room;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class GameController {

    private Game game;

    public GameController() {
        this.game = new Game(new ArrayList<Room>());
    }

    public boolean addRoom(Room room) {
        if (!game.getRooms().contains(room)) {
            return game.getRooms().add(room);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `GameController` code doesn't compile and is also missing `@Named`. Please don't write down untested code. Copypaste the real and tested code instead.

Comment: I've fixed it. Sorry. I've added `@Named` but it still doesn't work. I though that `@Named` is only for `EL`, thats why I didn't add this before.

Comment: Why @Named? Won't make any difference.

Comment: Just to clear it clear for everyone reading this, as Karl Kilden and pepuch pointed out, @Named is only required for EL.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make the bean a managed resource to make it eligible for injection. At the bare minimum, add `@RequestScoped` to the JAX-RS SIB to make it injection-worthy.

Another alternative annotation is `@ManagedBean`. The point is , Jersey won't address the desired injection target, if the parent bean is not in a managed context

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

@RequestScoped
@Path("room")
public class RoomService {

    @Inject
    GameController gc;

    public RoomService() {}

    @Path("create")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String create() {
        Room r = new Room();
        gc.addRoom(r); // gc is null
        return r.toJson();
    }
}
```

EDIT: be sure to have a **beans.xml** file in your WEB-INF folder. Your beans.xml file will look something like:

```
  <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">   

  </beans>
```

EDIT: Based on [this JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18793), you may replace `@RequestScoped` with `@ManagedBean`

Comment: Can you add an example? I've tried to add `@RequestScoped` to jax-rs class but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @pepuch,see my edit. Also make sure you have the beans.xml file in your WEB-INF or else CDI injection will not happen

Comment: @KarlKildén, it is weird, but it appears to work. The concept of a managed bean in JEE is applicable to all contexts so in theory, a managed bean can be present in any application/system in the JEE stack

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've got beans.xml so it should work but .. it doesn't. Temporarily I've created singleton, in free time I will try to do it in a beautiful way ;)

Answer (score 1):

*The built-in context object is active during servlet, web service and EJB invocations, or in the case of the conversation context object, for JSF requests.*

You may have difficulty accessing request,scope and application beans from JAX-RS service as it doesn't clearly states the support for this , however in your case it seems like you just need a singleton rather than a context based bean.

Keep it like this if you are using CDI (beans.xml),

```
@Singleton
public class GameController {
    private Game game;
    public GameController() {
        this.game = new Game(new ArrayList<Room>());
    }
....
}
```

If you are using CDI with Spring (no beans.xml) then keep the `@Named`

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class GameController {
    private Game game;
    public GameController() {
        this.game = new Game(new ArrayList<Room>());
    }
....
}
```

If the above doesn't work then I will suggest marking your JAX-RS service as `@ManagedBean` along with the above change as it is unclear if CDI manages JAX-RS service.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use `@Singleton`. Why I've used `@ApplicationScoped`? I'm new in JEE and I thought that `ApplicationScoped` bean will work like `Singleton`.

Comment: So `Singleton` is created for the whole jee container and `ApplicationScoped` is created only for application?

Comment: Cdi creates its own bean container if beans.xml is present and adds all the injection wherever required by creating new objects unless specified as singleton , then it uses the same copy of object. Applicationscoped are created and removed by cdi container when application context of web app is created,destroyed.

Comment: I have removed my last comment about using context on POJO. ApplicationScoped should work for POJO , in fact all contexts work for POJO and are mostly used on POJO. CDI BeanManager takes care of updating/activating the beans as the context is created for the component where the annotated beans are injected . It seems that context(for CDI) is not getting activated for JAX-RS component as it is not directly supported.

Comment: Spring has nothing to do with CDI. It uses some Java EE annotations but doesn't implement CDI. You cannot "use CDI with Spring". Also, beans.xml isn't required for CDI.

Answer (score -1):

Add [cdi-api.jar](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcdiapijar.htm) to your project.