# Unable to inject bean with cdi : NullPointerException

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Ok so I am new to CDI and currently facing problem while injecting bean. Here are details of module:

ResourceController.java

```
//imports

@Path("/resource")
public class ResourceController {

    @GET
    @Path("/print/{message}")
    public void printMessage(@PathParam("message") String message){
        MessagePrinter bean = new MessagePrinter();
        bean.print(message);
    }
}
```

MessagePrinter.java

```
//imports

public class MessagePrinter  {

    @Inject
    private InjectedBean bean;


    public void print(String message) {

        bean.print(message);    
    }

}
```

InjectedBean.java

```
public interface InjectedBean {
    public void print(String message);
}
```

InjectedBeanImp.java

```
public class InjectedBeanImp implements InjectedBean {

    public InjectedBeanImp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String message) {

        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

here the problem is that whenever I hit the resource  `ResourceController.java` , I get `NullPointerException` in `MessagePrinter.java`  class meaning injection of `InjectedBean.java` is failed.

Here is stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bean.MessagePrinter.print(MessagePrinter.java:14)
    at com.resource.ResourceController.printMessage(ResourceController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
```

Before anyone of you mark this as duplicate question ,I did lot of research on many threads for solution and eliminated some probable errors as :

1) switched from Tomcat to Tomee to rule out the possibility of server issue
2) I explicitly maintained the empty `beans.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder(which was unavailable by default)

but still I am stuck with the same problem and could not find any other solution. What is it that I am doing wrong?

**Update-1**

Here are contents of `beans.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.2" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">

    <!-- some content -->
</beans>
```

as can be seen  `bean-discovery-mode`  is "annotated" as it was correctly mentioned in one of the comments :)

So I annotated required beans as below:

ResourceController.java

```
//imports

@Path("/resource")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ResourceController {

    @Inject
    private IMessagePrinter bean;

    @GET
    @Path("/print/{message}")
    public void printMessage(@PathParam("message") String message){

        bean.print(message);
    }
}
```

MessagePrinter.java

```
//imports

@ApplicationScoped
public class MessagePrinter implements IMessagePrinter {

    @Inject
    private InjectedBean bean;


    public void print(String message) {

        bean.print(message);    
    }

}
```

Also I have now injected the interface for `MessagePrinter.java` i.e `IMessagePrinter.java` to `ResourceController.java` instead of creating instance
But now I am getting below exception :

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey RESTful Application] in context with path [/TestEJB] threw exception [A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=IMessagePrinter,parent=ResourceController,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,29372562)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.resource.ResourceController errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.resource.ResourceController
] with root cause
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=IMessagePrinter,parent=ResourceController,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,29372562)
```

Again I am stuck.
Thanks in advance for your patience :)

**Note:**
However if I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) approach without `beans.xml` it works fine but I don't want to do binding of implementations and interfaces explicitly.

Comment: What container are you deploying to?  I see tomee and jersey in the stack.  TomEE ships with CXF.  Ideally you shouldn't ship your own JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: `MessagePrinter bean = new MessagePrinter();` is definitely nonsense  - you want to inject it instead. Apart from that, do you have `beans.xml` with discovery set to `all`? If not, you beans won't be picked up as you do not use bean defining annotations.

Comment: @John Ament  :sorry but didn't really get your comment  _TomEE ships with CXF. Ideally you shouldn't ship your own JAX-RS implementation_

Comment: @jCoder its really hard to clarify if you don't answer the questions being presented.  Based on your stacktrace, it looks like you're deploying to tomee but shipping the jersey JAX-RS library with it.  Is that in fact what you are doing?

Comment: @John Ament: Sorry for late response. Yes I am using TomEE and jersey.

Comment: Looks a bit like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453350/unable-to-inject-applicationscoped-bean-in-jax-rs-service. Do you need ResourceController to be ApplicationScoped?

Comment: @ aschoerk tried with '@RequestScoped' and '@ManagedBean' as well but doesn't seem to make any difference , I get same error , also tried with discovery-mode=all but no luck with that either :(

Answer (score 2):

You should not create `MessagePrinter bean = new MessagePrinter();` but inject it `@Inject private MessagePrinter bean;`

Comment: tried that also , but gives me same error i.e. NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

In annotated mode you need to put a scope like @ApplicationScoped on the bean to be discovered. Maybe use all discovery mode if you want any bean.

Comment: As you can notice in update above, I have already annotated beans 'ResourceController.java' and 'MessagePrinter.java' with @ApplicationScoped. Still I am getting 'UnsatisfiedDependencyException'

Comment: Are you sure jersey uses cdi? Looks like it falls back on hk2 which doesnt know beans if you dont have the cdi extension

Answer (score 0):

In `beans.xml` you can change

`bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`

to

`bean-discovery-mode="all"`

As talex said, you should not use new keyword to create MessagePrinter because the CDI container is controlling the life cycle of MessagePrinter and by using `new` you are breaking it.